# Async Axios call not executed in Svelte: trying to use the result raises a TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object ; Fetch API working

Tags: axios, svelte, svelte-3

## Summary

- Context
- Actual behavior (Problem)
- Expected behavior
- Minimal, Testable, Executable Example

  - Data
  - Sources
- Notes
- Clues

---

## Context

I am trying to get a list of JSON objects from the URL `http://localhost:1337/restaurants` using Axios, in a Svelt Webapp. This call is censed to be executed when the Svelte component is initialized, similarly to the Svelte tutorial: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks.

## Actual behavior (Problem)

When I open the Web page containing the Svelte component, I don't see the network call in my Chromium dev tools network panel.

I can see this error shown in the Web page (obviously thanks to my `{:catch}`):

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

## Expected behavior

When I open the Web page containing the Svelte component, I should see the network call  in my Chromium dev tools network panel, and it should show each of the JSON objects in a list item.

Of course, the following error must not be raised:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

## Minimal, Testable, Executable Example

### Data

This example uses the (Strapi) URL `http://localhost:1337/restaurants`, which returns the following array of JSON objects:

> [{"id":1,"name":"Biscotte Restaurant","description":"Welcome to Biscotte restaurant! Restaurant Biscotte offers a cuisine based on fresh, quality products, often local, organic when possible, and always produced by passionate producers.","published_at":"2021-10-02T20:04:26.780Z","created_at":"2021-10-02T19:40:30.378Z","updated_at":"2021-10-02T20:04:26.816Z","categories":[{"id":2,"name":"Brunch","published_at":"2021-10-02T20:04:03.395Z","created_at":"2021-10-02T19:41:15.186Z","updated_at":"2021-10-02T20:04:03.437Z"}]}]

### Sources

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    async function getRestaurants() {
            return await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/restaurants');
    }

    let restaurants_promise = getRestaurants();
</script>

<main>
    {#await restaurants_promise}
        <p>wait...</p>
    {:then restaurants}
        <p>The restaurants are:</p>
        {#each restaurants.data as restaurant}
            <li>
                {restaurant.name}
            </li>
        {/each}
    {:catch error}
        <p style="color: red">{error}</p>
    {/await}
</main>
```

## Notes

I don't want to use Strapi's tutorial`onMount` and `then/catch` blocks as I prefer to follow the Svelte's tutorial (see the Strapi's tutorial: [the Strapi tutorial](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/integrations/svelte.html#get-request-your-collection-type)) ("Strapi" because in fact `http://localhost:1337/restaurants` is a Strapi URL). I really try to stick to https://svelte.dev/tutorial/await-blocks.

## Clues

- With Postman, I can actually get the URL list of JSON objects so the network call works. **So what is buggy is clearly my Svelte code.**
- With the Fetch API instead of Axios, my code works. I don't see anymore the error "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object".

Answer (score 8):

There seems to be an error in the code that merges the user's config with the defaultConfig of axios (somehow the defaultConfig is `undefined`).

This issue was introduced in v0.21.2 so downgrading to latest v0.21.1 should work for the time being.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: The issue still persists on version 0.24.0

Comment: And I was trying to debug _my_ code...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Svelte throw weird errors using an #each within an #await block. I solved this by adding an {#if} before the {#each}

```html
<main>
    {#await restaurants_promise}
        <p>wait...</p>
    {:then restaurants}
        <p>The restaurants are:</p>
{#if restaurants.data}
        {#each restaurants.data as restaurant}
            <li>
                {restaurant.name}
            </li>
        {/each}
{/if}
    {:catch error}
        <p style="color: red">{error}</p>
    {/await}
</main>
```

Comment: this is just because it's null ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in Axios v0.26.1 ([Changelog is here](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v0.26.1))

Comment: It diding worked for me :/

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you just need to await the actual data. Right now you're awaiting the call and then trying to iterate over the data.

```html
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    async function getRestaurants() {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:1337/restaurants');
            const data = await res.data
            return data 
    }

    let restaurants_promise = getRestaurants();
</script>

<main>
    {#await restaurants_promise}
        <p>wait...</p>
    {:then restaurants}
        <p>The restaurants are:</p>
        {#each restaurants as restaurant}
            <li>
                {restaurant.name}
            </li>
        {/each}
    {:catch error}
        <p style="color: red">{error}</p>
    {/await}
</main>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Seems we are getting a similar issue.

Is your full error anything like this?

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at mergeConfig (mergeConfig.js:92)